# LDRB and LDR problem in the ARM M0+ assembly

Tags: assembly, arm

```
ArraySize EQU 0X0A
        AREA array, DATA, READWRITE
        ALIGN
y_array SPACE ArraySize

        AREA sort, CODE, READONLY
        ENTRY
        THUMB
        ALIGN
        EXPORT __main
 __main PROC
        B __sort
  __ret
    
        ALIGN
        ENDP

 __sort PROC
        MOVS R0, #0
        LDR R1, =x_array
        LDR R3, =y_array
        CMP R5, #ArraySize
        BGE __ret
  __mem LDRB R2, [R1,R0]
        STRB R2, [R3,R0]
        ADDS R0, R0, #1
        B __mem
        ENDP

  x_array DCB 12,65,43,37,89,94,37,56,33,14
        END
```

I am newbie to assembly. The assembly code for ARM M0+ above is to copy array. I have some questions about that;

1. When I use `LDR R2, [R1,R0]` instead of `LDRB R2, [R1,R0]` there occurs error i couldn't define. I think the reason about x_array definition is DCB but i am not sure about it.
2. When I use `ALIGN` statement in the code and what is the clear purpose of the statement?
3. Is there any `RET` instruction for ARM M0+ assembly?

And please warn me if there is any error you recognize in the code. Thanks!!

Comment: _"When I use LDR R2, [R1,R0] instead of LDRB R2, [R1,R0] there occurs error i couldn't define"_. You should use the appropriate instruction for the data you're accessing, i.e. in this case `LDRB`.

Comment: 1 and 2 have the same answer: Alignment. For m3, it should be listed in whatever you are using to learn ARM.

Comment: where do you set r5 before comparing it?

Comment: bge __ret does not return it only takes you right back into __sort, it will be an infinite loop

Comment: likewise your __mem loop is inifinite so it will march through address space until it crashes

Comment: ldr expects an aligned address, incrementing the index will make it unaligned 75% of the time.  depends on how you setup the processor as to whether that causes a fault or not

Comment: dcb is not related you simply have a number of programming mistakes

Comment: how are you running this?  in a simulator?  you probably want to bl to sort but you need the stack setup first.  and then after that bl then do a bx lr to return from main (or label b label to end in an infinite loop)   then bx lr to return from sort back to main.  but first

Comment: psueidocode your way through this then code it.   you are close, set the index to zero.  set base address/pointers to the array labels.  then go into the loop, read one, store one, increment pointer, test pointer against array size, if not equal (or if unsigned less than) then go back to the top of the loop, else fall through to a return from sort

Answer (score 2):

1. The difference between `LDRB` and `LDR` is the size of the data.  If you are loading a byte (8 bits) use `LDRB`.  For a word (32 bits) use `LDR`.
2. The purpose of `ALIGN` is to skip some bytes so that the address of what follows is a certain multiple, usually a multiple of 4 if not otherwise specified.  Most data needs to be aligned to a multiple of the size of its members, eg: an array of 32-bit words need to be aligned to 4 bytes.
3. For ARMv6M (Cortex-M0, M0+ and M1) the instruction to return from a function is `bx lr` meaning *branch with exchange to address in link register*.  This is used in functions without anything on the stack or when the stack has already been popped.  Normally it is more efficient to pop any saved registers from the stack at the same time as returning.  This looks like `pop {r4-r6,pc}`.  The exact register list will depend on what you pushed, but the key is you will have pushed some registers including `lr` *link register*, which gets popped into `pc` *program counter*.

Comment: He also needs to understand condition codes and a conditional branch to only perform the copy 10 times as old_timer noted above.  Mainly everything else seems correct although you also need `blx sort` to put the address in the link register.  It comes to a question of OS hosting as to what is actually correct to 'return from main()`.